# PCIe NVMe can't resume from sleep

Tags: kernel, suspend, nvme

I recently replaced my NVMe PCIe Intel 660 with a WD SN750 512GB and simultaneously installed a fresh Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS as the only OS with UEFI boot.  Whenever the system sleeps and then I wake it up, the file system is in read-only mode.  If I simply reset the PC, the BIOS can't detect the drive until I power off the PC and turn it back on.

Obviously, there's no logs for the kernel because it can't write to the drive.  I can't determine if this is a BIOS issue, drive issue, or kernel issue.

I'm running kernel 5.4.0-42-generic

Kernel boot options attempted
pcie_aspm=disabled
acpiphp.disabled=1
nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=10000

Any suggestions as to what I can try?  Note that I don't have a Windows license to test the Windows drivers.

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to the suspend mode. Try adding these kernel parameters:

```
acpi_rev_override=1 acpi_osi=Linux mem_sleep_default=deep
```

Alternatively, the issue may lie in IOMMU. If the above did not work give a shot to

```
iommu=soft
```

Comment: Necroposting in hope it would help other people lost in google too